# Does watson learn other words or do I always have to teach?

Tags: watson

After teaching the IBM watson conversation with a few words, over time does he learn others related to the same subject or do I always have to put new words?

Comment: What Watson are you talking about?

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty  http://www.ibm.com/watson/

Comment: Watson is a whole range of products, which one specifically are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

After you teach Watson conversation a number of sample questions it can understand the relationship of the terms between the questions. Everything it knows at that point is what it will know.

If a new question appears that shares the same context, then Watson will be able to understand that it belongs to that intent.

If the new question has on shared context, then you need to add it to the training. You can do this through the improve UI.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have given the proper data while training the system, afterwards if you encounter some other related tags or keywords and intents, you have to add and train them manually.

Answer (score -1):

Pro Tip: Yes You Can!

According to the [Docs](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/): The service collects data from all requests and uses the data to improve the services.